# Is there an international definion of when a fetus is alive?

Tags: abortion

Is there any internationally recognised law that defines when, if ever, a fetus is considered alive and that terminating the pregnancy would be considered homicide?

Comment: There is no international law concerning the termination of a pregnancy. Every jurisdiction has its own laws

Comment: Super highly depending on the jurisdiction. As in, this depends so much on local law, that highest courts dealt and deal with legislation about this since the 50s.

Comment: While the question is badly written, politically charged, and based on wholly incorrect assumptions, it is answerable. A close vote is not a super-downvote.

Comment: Let me rephrase what was told you 5 times already: **There is no such thing as international law on abortion**.

Comment: Sex selection is a separate issue. Different jursidictions have different rules. If you want to ask about those laws then ask directly. Otherwise it is not relevant. Murder and related crimes are all matters of national legislation; there is no international law on this. International law is about relationships between states, not how states treat individuals. The only exception are laws about crimes against humanity as they can be prosecuted anywhere. But abortion is not considered such.

Comment: If the question is simply whether there is an international law regarding abortion, discussing the reasons that may or may not be true is irrelevant. I've removed them from the question.

Comment: Short answer: no, since 'International' law is basicly a compromise between parties. The comprise in this question is that human rights begin at birth. [Universal Declaration of Human Rights](https://www.un.org/en/universal-declaration-human-rights/) Article 1 *All human beings are **born** free and equal in dignity and rights*. See also: [Fetal rights - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetal_rights)

Comment: As edited, the question can be objectively answered. It should be reopened, and should IMO have been edited rather than being closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Labeling an abortion as "homicide" would be a matter of criminal law and generally not the subject of international law.

There are no international laws or treaties limiting a woman's right to choose to terminate her pregnancy. On the contrary, international agreements are generally understood to protect a woman's right to terminate her pregnancy and do not attempt to define fetal viability or otherwise establish a point at which a fetus is treated as a life entitled to legal protection and recognition.

For instance, the UN Human Rights Committee’s [General Comment on the Right to Life](https://www.ohchr.org/Documents/HRBodies/CCPR/CCPR_C_GC_36.pdf) says that states may regulate abortions, but those regulations must not "must not result in violation of the right to life of a pregnant woman or girl," and must not "jeopardize their lives, subject them to physical or mental pain or suffering which violates article 7, discriminate against them or arbitrarily interfere with their privacy."

Laws governing medical abortions are jurisdiction-specific, and the [Center for Reproductive Rights](https://reproductiverights.org/worldabortionlaws) has a helpful guide to the legality of abortion in different countries.